# Multiple mysqli connections or pass the connection object

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

Hi I'm new to databases and have only recently got to grips with php.

I'm writing a simulator for an online game and have a 'Match' class.

Each simulation is run as an instance of this object by calling
`$match->simulate();`

Is it correct for each instance to create its own connection to the database for reading and writing or should I create a master connection and pass it to the simulate function in each 'Match' object?

I'm using mysqli in the object oriented syntax.

Which would provide better performace and/or reliability.
I'm hoping when the game goes live to be simulating hundreds to thousands of matches simultaneously.

ADDITION:

Thanks for the quick answer. Can you expand on it for mine and others benefit explaining why a master connection is preferred.

I'd like to accept the answer that is most informative :-) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a master connection and pass it to the simulate function in each 'Match' object. It will provide better performance and/or reliability.

Being new to something, always use Occam's razor to identify your needs. Do you have any practical (but not imaginary!) need in extra database connections? If not - then be content with single one. Entities must not be multiplied beyond necessity

Comment: Good enough for me :-)